# Perl oneliner regex

Tags: perl

I have created this regex script online, to strip bracket out of string `[/apache/20160419/20160419-0643/20160419-064309-VxYLvX8AAAEAABumDlIAAAAG]`

I'm wondering if it is possible to run it on the shell as "perl oneliner"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# URL that generated this code:
# http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=[/apache/20160419/20160419-0643/20160419-064309-VxYLvX8AAAEAABumDlIAAAAG]&2

$txt='[/apache/20160419/20160419-0643/20160419-064309-VxYLvX8AAAEAABumDlIAAAAG]';

$re1='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='((?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+)';  # Unix Path 1

$re=$re1.$re2;
if ($txt =~ m/$re/is)
{
    $unixpath1=$1;
    print $unixpath1;
}
```

I have tried

```
cat file | perl -wnE'say /((?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+)/g'
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(( <-- HERE ?:\\/ at -e line
```

Comment: Please expand on what you're after. This is a very complicated approach to what looks like a really simple problem.

Comment: Where does the data in `$txt` come from, please?

Comment: State your question (it is not clear to me) as the title. *Perl oneliner regex* is not a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed`, but perl works too:

```
echo "[foo]" | perl -pe 's/[\[\]]//g'
```

Though i'm not sure why you want to use such a complicated regex just to remove braces.

Answer (score 3):

Seems overly complicated for what amounts to:

```
 $txt =~ s/(^\[|\]$)//g;
```

Or if fed the whole URL, and as a one liner:

```
perl -ne 'print m/\[([^]]+)\]/;'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what you want, but this will strip *all* square brackets from a string supplied on the command line

```
$ perl -E "say shift =~ tr/[]//dr" [/apache/20160419/20160419-0643/20160419-064309-VxYLvX8AAAEAABumDlIAAAAG]
/apache/20160419/20160419-0643/20160419-064309-VxYLvX8AAAEAABumDlIAAAAG
```

or this will print the first sequence of characters that aren't square brackets, with the same result given this data

```
$ perl -E "say shift =~ / ( [^\[\]]+ ) /x" [/apache/20160419/20160419-0643/20160419-064309-VxYLvX8AAAEAABumDlIAAAAG]
/apache/20160419/20160419-0643/20160419-064309-VxYLvX8AAAEAABumDlIAAAAG
```